# Widget below ListView.builder / Flexible take minimum space

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I want to create a Column Widget, where I have two elements:
a ListView.builder (had to be wrapped in a Flexible Widget so, it doesnt crash) and another Widget.
The other Widget shall be placed directly below the ListView.

The problem is that The Flexible Widget/ListView takes all the space and pushes the other widget to the bottom of the screen.

I already tried various combinations of putting the other Widget into a second Flexible, too and playing around with flex and fit, but nothing seemed to work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> mylist = ["aaaa","bbbb","cccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: Column(
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: listbuilder,itemCount: mylist.length,)),
      ListTile(leading: Text("this should be below the other"))
      ]),)

    );
  }

  Widget listbuilder(BuildContext context, int index)
  {
    return ListTile(leading: Text(mylist[index]),

    );
  }
}
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
            body:
                      Column(verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down, children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: listbuilder,
                      itemCount: mylist.length,
                    ),
                    ListTile(leading: Text("this should be below the other"))
                  ]),
```